# How to setup WCF Net.Tcp

Tags: wcf, nettcpbinding

I'm trying to setup a wcf service to use net.tcp over IIS 7.

Here is the error I get:

> There was no endpoint listening at
>   net.tcp://127.0.0.1:8000/ListingService
>   that could accept the message. This is
>   often caused by an incorrect address
>   or SOAP action. See InnerException, if
>   present, for more details.

Here is the code I call from the client:

```
using (var client = new ListingServiceClient("NetTcpBinding"))
{
   client.Test();
   client.Close();
}
```

Here is my services web.config - http://pastebin.com/3S8BZbup

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding portSharingEnabled="true">
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="default">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <!--throttle service-->
          <serviceThrottling
            maxConcurrentCalls="10000"
            maxConcurrentSessions="10000" 
            maxConcurrentInstances="10000" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="default" name="Housters.Services.ListingService">
        <endpoint name="TcpEndpoint"
                  address="net.tcp://127.0.0.1:8000/ListingService"
                  binding="netTcpBinding"
                  contract="Housters.Services.IListingService" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
      <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
```

And here is my client app.config - http://pastebin.com/YpiAhh46

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="NetTcpBinding">
          <security mode="None"/>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint
              address="net.tcp://127.0.0.1:8000/ListingService"
              binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding"
              contract="ListingServiceProxy.IListingService" name="NetTcpBinding" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I should also mention that I have added net.tcp in the iis enabled protocols and have added a binding for net.tcp - "8000:*".

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem, but I noticed you don't set the `bindingConfiguration` property on the "TcpEndpoint" `endpoint`.  nor do you have a `name` set on the `netTcpBinding`.

Comment: Are we looking at the same code? On the tcp endpoint I'm setting the bindingConfiguration: bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding". I'm also setting the name on the netTcpBinding: <binding name="NetTcpBinding">. Let me know if I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: configs added - no problems at all....

Comment: the server config. lines 55 and 30 in the pastebin link

Comment: I tried setting the binding name & endpoint bindingconfiguration but still get the same error.

Comment: Could you try to self-host the server, just for a test, inside a console app?? IIS and net.tcp aren't exactly buddies....

Comment: How exactly would that work? I have multiple methods within the service, would I need to have a separate port/endpoint listening for each method?

Comment: @Justin: Create a Console App.  Add a reference to WCF Project dll, add an App.config file to the Console App.  Copy web.config to app.config. In Main(), add code to create and open a ServiceHost, and Console.ReadKey().  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731758.aspx

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't seem to work. I'm able to create a self-hosted service and start it without any errors, however when I try to add service reference, it errors: There was an error downloading 'http://localhost:8080/ListingService'.
Unable to connect to the remote server
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8080
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://localhost:8080/ListingService'.
There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost:8080/ListingService that could accept the message.

Comment: Got it working! I was doing a windows service instead of a console app and it didn't have sufficient permission to open the service host. Can you please post your comments as an answer so I can give you credit?

Comment: I'm confused. what was the cause of the problem? was it that you were not hosting the server correctly?  perhaps IIS not getting along with net.tcp, like marc_s suggested?

Comment: OK good to know, thanks. I still have no idea why it didn't work with iis, but I was able to get it working with the "self-hosted" solution in a windows service, and I'm ok with that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This configuration will not work in IIS/WAS. When hosting in IIS you need .svc file (or configuration based activation in WCF 4) and address of the endpoint is always VirtualDirectoryPath + SvcFile + Relative address specified in endpoint configuration. Setting absolute address in endpoint configuration is for self hosting.

Comment: what do you call VirtualDirectoryPath?